# Unity apk not working without usb debugging

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, apk

Game apk works on installed device, when my phone connected to usb on Unity Editor (2019.2.13f1). But it doesn’t work on device with installed apk without usb. Actually, main scene opens, but it stopped working on load scene. I’ve searched for solutions (deleted package.json to give chance to unity install all again etc.). Still getting same errors.

Comment: have you getting any error in log when connected again?

Comment: when u install with usb , you installing debug version. I think you must check configuration of release options.seek issue there

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1425828/scenemanagerloadscene-is-crashing-or-freezing-for.html?_ga=2.56934122.177496045.1578914700-656834343.1574709842